how do I remove the space between 2 td while still having their height 100% without overflowing?
So I am doing a fun thing for myself and I chose html4 and css2, yes you read that right, html4 and css2 :D
Here is my page:


html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Allow scrolling within content */
}
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="2" id="header">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="main">
    <td valign="top">
      <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <div id="content">content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



the problem is that the sidebar td and content td have this weird space in the middle that's 100% width(?) which seems to push the 2 tds the the far left and right:
I just cant figured it out how, I did it once but I forgot how to do it now. could someone please help me with this...and please use html4 with css2 only for the sake of retro/nostalgia :D (I absolutely adore web 1.0). and no, I dont just want the look, I want the code too :D

There's no space between <td>s. Add a border to td and you'll see. BTW, overflow is CSS3.

If you are serious use this at the top of your document: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">. Hey you can use <frame>

well yes overfow is css3, but what I truly mean is that there is usually a space at the bottom which is equal to the heiht of the top td or div whatever so I tried to remove that but now there's another space which is more annoying than the bottom space T^T

and yes, for the sake of retro I added doctype for html4 :D

wait really? but the content inside them is tho, how do I fix that is the thing

There is a CSS2 property to control the exact width of each <td>. You can even use %, it's table-layout.

hmm I removed that off my css, lemme add that back in then teak it a little to see what happens

omg so it works by mving the id sidebar and content to the tds inside of the divs inside them and add the width of 150px to the div inside sidebar td :0

width: 100% isn't going to stretch the td but explicitly setting td content like a <div> width: Npx will stretch td.

overflow is CSS2. overflow-y is CSS3. In your case you can use overflow: auto and keep your CSS level 2 pure. And the doctype @zer00ne gave you is wrong. Use either <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> or <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">, not a mix of the two.

@Alohci  Correction: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"> I'm sure I'm not going to lose any sleep over it.

CSS code updated. No white space.


html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 100%; /* changed from 150px to 100% */
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Allow scrolling within content */
}
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="2" id="header">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="main">
    <td valign="top" style="width: 150px;"> <!-- inline css -->
      <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <div id="content">content</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




omg thankyou so much this works too altho I found the answer stil I'm gonna take a note of this <3
